# New blank email created on Outlook start up

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Whenever I start up Outlook I get two annoying new windows which is two blank new emails. These emails are being automatically saved in Draft folder and I have to delete them manually. I have no idea how to get rid of this.

NB: My Outlook version is 2007.

Image of blank emails:
[image]

Comment: Try holding the Ctrl key and opening Outlook. That will open Outlook in safe mode and help you to determine if it is a plugin. Most likely it is a plugin or startup item in Outlook.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The culprit was add-in named "VSTO Multiple Email". If you write your comment as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold `Ctrl` and open Outlook. This will open Outlook in safe mode and allow you to determine if it is a plugin or startup item. If the problem is resolved you can then use a process of elimination by going in and individually disabling add-ins in Outlook until you find the culprit.